# How to make a conditional type annotation?

Tags: typescript

How can I conditionally make [type annotations on variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables). I've got a function with an argument that is changing the behaviour of an api call. The behaviour is changed in such a way that the response differs. I want to type that but wasn't able to to do so after hours of research.

Thats the situation ("PseudoCode").

```
async search(withDetails = false) {
  const query = {
    withDetails
  }
  const data: MyApiResponse = await axios.post(uri, query)
}
```

That's what I want to achieve.

```
async search(withDetails = false) {
  const query = {
    withDetails
  }
  const data: withDetails ? ResponseWithDetails : ResponseWithoutDetails = await axios.post(uri, query)
}
```

Comment: Here, I think that is what are you looking for.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code may see either type at runtime, you have to allow for both. Usually you'd use a union type, and then when you need to know whether there are details, you'd look at some aspect of the response that tells you whether there are details (for instance, check the presence of a property that only exists on `ResponseWithDetails`; I've used `details` in the example):

```typescript
async search(withDetails = false) {
    const query = {
        withDetails
    };
    const data: ResponseWithDetails | ResponseWithoutDetails = (await axios.post(uri, query)).data;
    // ...code that uses the common parts of that type...
    // If code needs to know there are details:
    if ("details" in data) {
        // Here, TypeScript knows `data` is `ResponseWithDetails`
    } else {
        // Here, TypeScript knows `data` is `ResponseWithoutDetails`
    }
}
```

(Note the slight unrelated modification to the code: `axios` wraps the response in an `AxiosResponse` object. The actual data is available as the `data` property, so I added using that data property.)

This avoids using any type assertions (`as whatever`), which is generally best when you can avoid it because it's easy to make a false type assertion and find your types don't accurately reflect the runtime values they're supposed to reflect.

---

In comments you've said that you don't actually use `data` in the function, you just want to return it to the caller. You can do that with a [*function overload*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#overloaded-functions), like this:

```typescript
async search(): Promise<ResponseWithoutDetails>;
async search(withDetails: false): Promise<ResponseWithoutDetails>;
async search(withDetails: true): Promise<ResponseWithDetails>;
async search(withDetails: boolean): Promise<ResponseWithoutDetails | ResponseWithDetails>; // See note on this one
async search(withDetails = false): Promise<ResponseWithoutDetails | ResponseWithDetails> {
    const query = {
        withDetails
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(uri, query);
    return data;
}
```

(You only need the declaration with `See note on this one` on it if you want to allow a runtime boolean value when calling `search`; if you want to **require** a compile-time constant, just remove that one.)

How that works is that when the argument is provided *as a compile-time constant* (like a literal `true` or `false`), TypeScript will know that the type is `ResponseWithDetails` or `ResponseWithoutDetails` respectively. It'll also know that a call with no argument will return `ResponseWithoutDetails`. It's only if you provide it with a *runtime* `boolean` value as an argument that the caller will see `ResponseWithoutDetails | ResponseWithDetails`.

Note that in the paragraph above I left off the `Promise<...>` for clarity, but of course the real types are `Promise<ResponseWithoutData>` and `Promise<ResponseWithData>`. But when you `await search`, the result is the fulfillment value of hte promise (`ResponseWithoutData` or `ResponseWithData`).

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-uWZV3XSsi3MAAmfdDyrJBTzaGVOiOcIL0fNk6jvB86mfV8oHfAEgS-Gc4HnRdSQZNcVlA7cEAAZigqNj1gs8unwk4cyvdD70vNllB4GRQFYTFsTaDhCJ-OA-whACySA-Y9RpKSyIpCiLU3MCEAAFnoo8T2YzoAFlgz0WNcI4KhcC7EY4AABljABWFCsLQ2oMO8bpW3IIA)

---

One final note: I made a point about not using type assertions when you can avoid it, and I stand by that point, but it's important to remember that when you're at the interface between TypeScript and the untyped world (the data you get back from axios), you're always doing a type assertion in some sense. (We could move it into a type argument on the `axios.post` call, but that's basically still there.) But if you do them in nice contained places like your `search`, you're safely back in typed land from there on. :-)

Comment: thank you this helped me understand the example from the documentation now. I understand why you prefer this pattern but I just want to return data to the upper function.

Comment: @MatthisKohli - If you're using the type assertions in the other answer, you're basically doing the union thing above, just returning the union from the function. Then the code in the other function has to figure out which it got (using a type guard as in this answer). (**Note:** I am not suggesting you change accepted answer, Use what works for you!)

Comment: Crowder you're right I thought TypeScript is going to figure it out with the help of the boolean parameter but it doesn't. I don't like the `magic string` there. Is it possible to do something like `if (keyOf ResponseWithDetails["id"]) {}` ?

Comment: @MatthisKohli - I've updated the answer to handle that case. This is where you want to use a function overload.

Comment: Function overload solved it! I tried both of your approaches but always received the same return type no matter what boolean I passed. Probably due to my limited knowledge. But this function overload worked out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this way

```
async search(withDetails = false) {
  const query = {
    withDetails
  }
  const response = await axios.post(uri, query)
  const data = withDetails ? response as ResponseWithDetails : response as ResponseWithoutDetails
}
```

Comment: It's really easy to trip yourself up with type assertions, though; best to avoid them.

Comment: Hmm I think we don't know the type of `await axios.post(uri, query)`. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: True (in this specific case), but we know from the question it'll be one of the two. But it's really easy to use the wrong one via a type assertion. Type guards are more reliable in that regard.

Comment: actually, we also can use `ResponseWithDetails` for both response types, and `details` value is optional, if data has no details, it won't be populated, but it also depends on the author's purposes.